# How to get a direct link to a particular answer?

Tags: support, questions, answers, links

I'm kinda sure that I have seen direct links to answers posted before. How can I get a link to a particular answer? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions and answers are followed by several links, one of which is "share." Clicking "share" opens a little modal window with the permalink in a text box and a button that lets you copy it to your clipboard.  But you can also right-click (or long-tap) the "share" link and copy it to the clipboard using the context menu in your browser, same as other links.

The "share" link includes your user number after the question/answer ID number.  If you don't want people who follow your link to know that it came from you, it's fine to leave the user number off.  The user-identified links are how you earn the [Announcer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer), [Booster](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/booster), and [Publicist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist) badges.

For a direct link to a specific *comment*, right-click its timestamp.